# Is there a Google Code-like web application to install on your own web and svn server?

Tags: webapp-rec, wiki, bug-trackers, google-code

Is there a [Google Code](http://code.google.com)-like web application to install on your own server which supports:

- Source code versioning, e.g. with subversion, git, mercurial...
- Wiki
- Issue tracker

All in one?

Comment: This might be better asked at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

We use Redmine (http://www.redmine.org/) which provides a wiki, ticket tracking and (some) subversion integration. It also provides support for forums (which we aren't using at the moment). Might be worth a look.

Comment: and you get get it all pre-packaged: http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine

Answer (score 1):

Fog Creek Software offers a [FogBugz and Kiln bundle package](http://fogcreek.com/Kiln/Bundle.html).  This includes bug tracking/project management, a Wiki, and source control, all tightly integrated.  Kiln runs on top of Mercurial and provides a great web interface for browsing code, managing repos, and doing code reviews.

Unlike Google code, however, Kiln is currently private.  That is, you have to have an account to access code (I'm not sure if public was a requirement for you or not).

Free, hosted "Student & Startup" accounts are available for up to 2-users.

*Full disclosure: I work for Fog Creek.*

Answer (score 0):

In my last company, we successfully used [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/) (DNN) as a wiki, a knowledge base and source code repository. It was .Net oriented, but could be easily configured for other code pieces (we had Java code as well)

Answer (score 0):

In my company we use Trac http://trac.edgewall.org/

> Trac is an enhanced wiki and issue tracking system for software
>   development projects. It provides an interface to  Subversion (or
>   other version control systems), an integrated Wiki and convenient
>   reporting facilities.
>
> Trac allows wiki markup in issue descriptions and commit messages,
>   creating links and seamless references between bugs, tasks,
>   changesets, files and wiki pages. A timeline shows all current and
>   past project events in order, making the acquisition of an overview of
>   the project and tracking progress very easy. The roadmap shows the
>   road ahead, listing the upcoming milestones.

Answer (score 0):

Assembla offers hosted installations as well.

We use SVN + Trac internally (includes Wiki) on a low cost Linux server.